# how to restart single apache site on a ubuntu vps rather than all sites

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I've got a ubuntu vps and apache mod wsgi installed and serving my django sites.

however i have to restart all of apache rather than the site i have amended and its going to be a bit shonky if i tell clients that i have restarted their site cos i updated another site.

is there a tutorial somewhere to teach me how to configure this? i couldnt find one in googles keywords soup.

I'm already using virtualenvs if it helps.

Comment: Why do you need to restart for changes? (I'm clueless about mod wsgi or django if that's the reason.) Do you really just need to clear a cache somewhere in mod wsgi or apache?

Comment: because when you start a django app it saves/sets up certain things for usage later like model registrations and settings.

if i were just editing a template then i wouldnt need to restart apache as it figures the changes out.

Comment: At least you can use apache's reload directive instead of restart...
@Rup another restart case, if you need to reload the compiled messages (mo files) you need to restart the app

Comment: check as well safe restarts, or gracefull restart, where each apache process is restarted when he have nothing to do, you do not break any existing request handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use `mod_wsgi` in daemon mode on UNIX/Apache 2.X system to run Django and have shell access to your machine all you need to do is touch the wsgi configuration for your project.

```
touch your_project.wsgi
```

See `mod_wsgi` documentation on [Reloading Source Code](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Reloading_In_Daemon_Mode) and [Django - `mod_wsgi` wiki](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/django_apache_and_mod_wsgi) for more references.